# Nuxt 3 server router does not response

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have followed the documentation of "Advanced usage" https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/server-routes#advanced-usage-examples

Now i tried it out:

My folder is structured like this:

```
server\api\global.ts
```

Here is my file `global.ts`

```
import { createRouter } from "h3";

const router = createRouter();

router.get("/", () => "Hello World");

export default router;
```

Now i try to fetch some data:

```
export const Bloggy = {
  login({ password, username }: LoginParameterI) {
    return $fetch("/api/global", {
      method: "GET",
    });
  },
};

interface LoginParameterI {
  password: string;
  username: string;
}
```

Now when i try to fetch some data, i receive an error:

```
[nuxt] [request error] Invalid lazy handler result. It should be a function
```

I wanted to use it with router, because i want to use certain middlewares for certain routes. In the nuxt documentation the middlewares will get triggered on every route

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Seems related to this one: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/4235